# Hard disk spins down and up too frequently when on battery

Tags: hard-disk, debian, laptop-mode

I'm using Debian Wheezy

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.3 (wheezy)
Release:    7.3
Codename:   wheezy


$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

on Lenovo G580 with Seagate 1TB Hard Disk.
The problem I'm facing is that the hard disk spins down and up too frequently when on battery. I tried using `hdparm` and used the following commands, but that didn't work. Also installed `laptop-mode` and edited `laptop-mode-conf`  to

```
LM_AC_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=2000
LM_BATT_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=2000
NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200
```

after reading similar posts, but that too didn't work, and so, I uninstalled it.

Comment: Assuming you tried these things? http://superuser.com/questions/555400/what-do-different-values-of-hard-drives-advanced-power-management-feature-hdpa

Comment: but will it be in effect when the laptop is running on battery than AC ?

Answer (score 2):

The cause is `hdparm`, there is a bug in there that spins down the HDD in 3-5 sec when idle. This has been known in `hdparm` since 2012 and reported fixed. Now it causes the same problems in Debian Wheezy (for me it was **Debian 7.6** and not before that initial upgrade to 7.6).

Solution:

- check what level you power management is on (*Advanced power management level*) with  `hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep level`
- open `/etc/hdparm.conf` and change the level to `128` on battery for `-B`, read the file comments on how to do this properly (*examples below in permanent solution*)
- alternatively if you don't want to edit the file, just run the command `hdparm -B 128 /dev/sdb` for your drive and set the *Advanced power management level* to prefer performance over power conservation
- if you don't want to touch the power management, run the command `hdparm -S 24 /dev/sda` (*24*5=120 seconds*) and change the spindown time to a value of your choice.

For a more permanent solution add this block to your `/etc/hdparm.conf` file

```
command_line {
     hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda
}
```

or this block

```
/dev/sda {
     apm_battery = 128
}
```

Then restart your hdparm deamon via `service hdparm restart` or `/etc/init.d/hdparm restart`. Reboot for verification.

Check the [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man8/hdparm.8.html) pages for an explanation of all of the above commands.

Comment: currently what i do is hdparam -B 255 /dev/sda and hdparam -S 255 /dev/sda. which turns off APM and sets the time offset to 21 mins.But have to do this everytime laptop go on battery as it gets reset when back on AC.

Comment: Yes it resets it back, but it fixed the problem for me nonetheless. It doesn't spindown the hdd anymore when on battery.

Comment: yes it does solve the issue for me too but, was looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: No, I meant to say that it solves it permanently even after I switch back to AC power and hdparm resets the APM value. When I switch back to battery, although the APM remains the same I don't need to change it as I find that the hdd doesn't spindown anymore.

Comment: One more thing, I also disabled hdd spindown in my GUI power manager for both AC and battery power (Xfce for me). It seams to be working well with hdparm. Try removing hdparm altogether and see if your hdd spinsdown then. You can always install it again and reconfigure.

Comment: I have changed my answer, try the permanent solution which I have already mentioned in the answer before.